# Unicode for Contextual forms of ټ,ګ,ځ,څ,ڼ,ښ,ډ,ۍ,ړ,ې in Pashto language

Tags: unicode, utf-8, localization, utf-16, ucs2

I am developing a program that give the correct format of text for example if I write **سلام** so it give `FEB3, FEE0, FE8E and FEE2` witch are Unicode of **سـ, ـلـ,ﺎ,ـم**, then if I write **ټول** there is Unicode for character **ټ** which is `067C`, but there is not Unicode for character **ټـ** which is **Initial Contextual form**.

So I found **Unicode** for isolated of  **ټ,ګ,ځ,څ,ڼ,ښ,ډ,ۍ,ړ,ې** in the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode), but I can't find **Unicode** of Contextual forms.

For example **Unicode** of **ټـ ,ـټـ,ـټ**.

I am waiting for response if any one knows the solution of this problem.
thanks...

Comment: [The spec](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch09.pdf#G37489) doesn't help…?

Answer (score 5):

A Unicode character is intended to be abstract in the sense that it doesn't have a particular presentation form. The preferred way to display cursive scripts like Arabic is to store the standard, non-contextual forms, and convert them to their cursive forms at display time - that is, as one of the final stages of a text display system in an operating system or word processor.

The cursive forms are usually provided as glyphs in the font, and are chosen using information in tables in the font file embodying the contextual rules.

Unicode stores quite a large number of Arabic contextual forms, but only for compatibility with older encodings, and with traditional metal type, for which only a finite number of physical glyphs can be supplied. Unfortunately for your purposes, these contextual forms don't cover all the extended characters used in languages other than Arabic, such as the example you give, which is U+067C ARABIC LETTER TEH WITH RING, used in Pashto.

It's very unlikely that further contextual Arabic forms will be added, in my opinion. Therefore your proposed program cannot be made to work, at least according to its current design.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier Unicode versions included separate codes for the different forms of Arabic letters for all letters except some.  Arabic letters are used to write Pashto, Farsi, Urdu, and few other languages.  The letters that were used in Arabic, Farsi, and may be a couple more languages were assigned different codes for each form of the their letters.  However, the letters used only by less taught languages like Pashto, which you are asking about, were assigned codes for only the isolated forms. In the later versions of the Unicode, it was decided to only assign a single code to each letter, leaving Pashto only letters to have codes for only the isolated forms. 
Actually there was no need to have a separate code for each form which was a bad decision made by the earlier Unicode versions. A rendering engine (editors, and other programs that deal with plain text) should account for the different forms of each letter and display the correct form according to its position.

Comment: Please don't post text walls.

Comment: This post is fine. The term 'text wall' is not helpful.